# I don't know why these codes will not encounter an IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
        checked = {}
        i = 0
        while target - nums[i] not in checked:
            print(i)
            checked[nums[i]] = i
            i += 1

        return [checked[target - nums[i]], i]

print(Solution().twoSum([3, 2, 4], 6))
```

I wonder why line #5 will not have an IndexError when doing the while loop.

For example, nums = [3, 2, 4], and target = 6. After executing lines #5 and #6, when i=2, i grows to 3 for the next while loop, but nums[3] will raise an IndexError normally. However, it doesn't actually. Why these codes can correctly solve the question without raising an Error?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], i.e. add the main method which calls the function with the values that don't work as expected

Comment: Have you tried running this code step by step in your debugger? `i` never has the value `3`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/KobfKCEda4jxBe6v

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE which has a debugger, e.g. [PyCharm Community edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). It's free and everyone who is programming needs to know [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

A debugger allows you to step through your code line by line and it will show you the contents of the variables after each line. While you do that, always compare that against what you expect your program will do.

Step through your code line by line using a debugger and you'll see it never throws an IndexError because it never reaches a situation where the code accesses an invalid index:

1. checked is `{}`
2. i is 0
3. the while loop is entered, because checked is empty
4. checked becomes `{3:0}`
5. i becomes 1
6. `target-nums[i]` is 4, it's not in the dictionary
7. checked becomes `{3:0, 2:1}`
8. i becomes 2
9. `target - nums[i]` is 6-4 is 2. It's in the dictionary
10. The while loop is skipped
11. returns `[checked[2], 2]` which is `[1, 2]`

Here's how the debug information looks like:

[image: PyCharm debug information]

Answer (score 0):

The while loop terminates when i reaches 2 as the expression in while gets evaluated to false as shown below.
'''

1. when i = 0
   while expression evaluates to true,
   target - nums[0] -> 6 - 3  -> 3 not in checked -> yes
   checked = {3:0}
2. when i = 1
   while expression evaluates to true,
   target - nums[1] -> 6 - 2 -> 4 not in checked -> yes
   checked = {3:0, 2:1}
3. when i = 2
   while expression evaluates to false and loop terminates here,
   target - nums[2] -> 6 - 4 -> 2 not in checked -> false
4. return statement executes
   return [checked[target - nums[i]], i] -> return [ checked[6 - 4], 2] ->
   return [checked[2], 2]  -> return [1,2]
   '''

Hope it is clear